# Как поместить таблицу в кэш EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

Программа рекурсивно обрабатывает директории и через `COM` читает специфические свойства определенных файлов. Новые свойства могут определяться пользователем, и быть доступными только у определенного файла. При чтении свойств мне нужно проверять есть ли уже в БД такое свойство и при его отсутствии добавлять, но как избежать запроса к БД для каждого сравнения?

Также не могу разобраться как после сохранения записи в Files и в Property добавить запись в FileProperties?

Заранее премного благодарен за уделенное время и внимание.

[image: Схема БД]

```cs
foreach(var path in paths){

  Files file;

  using(var context = new DbContext()){
    file = context.FirstOrDefault(f => ... );
  }

  if(file == null){

    file = new Files(){ ... };

    using(var context = new DbContext()){
      context.Files.Add(file);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }

    var specProps = GetSpecProps(path);

    using(var context = new DbContext()){

      foreach(var specProp in specProps){

        Property prop;

        // отправляет запрос на сервер, а как читать из "кеша"?
        prop = context.Property.FirstOrDefault( p => ...);

        if(prop == null){
          prop = new Property(){ ... };
          context.Property.Add(prop);
        }

        // как здесь добавить запись в FileProperties?
        // System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 
        // Не удалось обновить набор EntitySet "FileProperties", 
        // поскольку в нем имеется запрос DefiningQuery и 
        // отсутствует элемент <InsertFunction> в элементе 
        // <ModificationFunctionMapping> для поддержки текущей операции.
        // context.FileProperties.Add(new FileProperties() {
        //     File = file,
        //     Property = prop,
        //     property_value = specProp.Value.ToString()
        // };
      }
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: может попробовать хранить таблицу в переменной или в классе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианта тут два.

Вариант первый: вы загружаете таблицу на клиент целиком и помещаете в словарь для быстрого поиска по ней в памяти. Разумеется, это будет работать только если таблица маленькая:

```
var allProps = context.Properties.ToDictionary(p => p.property_name);
```

Только не надо в таком случае создавать по контексту БД на каждый файл, да еще и два раза. Вы можете в одном и том же контексте записать в БД сразу все файлы. За одну операцию сохранения.

---

Вариант второй. Надо ввести новую сущность, которая не будет иметь отображения в БД. Вместо этого, операция вставки будет отображена на хранимую процедуру, которая проверит существование свойства и создаст его при необходимости, после чего вернет ключ найденного или созданного свойства.

Comment: огромное спасибо за Ваш ответ. Сейчас, для "кеширования" использую после using `dbContext.TableName.Load()`, а запросы затем выполняю так `dbContext.TableName.Local.Where( ... )`. Так тоже можно? Или есть какие-то особенности?

Comment: @XelaNimed да, так тоже можно - но будет медленнее (все-таки линейный поиск).

Comment: Вышеприведенный вариант с `dbContext.TableName.Load()` и `dbContext.TableName.Local.Where( ... )` не приводит к увеличению производительности и даже наоборот - снижает ее после увеличения таблицы до нескольких тысяч записей.